# testing angular components with jest gives resolveComponentResources

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest, jest-preset-angular

I'm trying to test Angular components with jest via `jest-preset-angular`

it can run the test by `karma` with `ng test`,
but running the same test by `jest` gives the error

```
AppComponent › should create the app

    Component 'AppComponent' is not resolved:
     - templateUrl: ./app.component.html
     - styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
    Did you run and wait for 'resolveComponentResources()'?
```

[reproduction](https://github.com/eng-dibo/reprod-resolveComponentResources/blob/main/README.md)

### steps to create this reproduction (see the git commits for steps)

1- generate a new angular project `ng new myproject`
2- install jest dependencies
3- create jest config file
4- copy and modify `src/app/app.component.spec.ts` to `app.component.spec.jest.ts`

### running the reproduction

to test `app.component.spec.ts` file by karma run `npm t` or `ng test`
and then run `npm run test:jest` to test `app.component.spec.jest.ts` by jest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is detailed here: https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/951

For my part it worked when I added the following in `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular'
  },
};
```

They also suggest setting up this in `jest.preset.js`, but that wasn't necessary for me...

```
const nxPreset = require('@nrwl/jest/preset');

module.exports = {
   ...nxPreset,
   testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
   transform: {
      '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular'
   }
};
```

Comment: You have no idea how much time I spent until I found your answer. thanks!